# jQuery toggle on a <div> not working

Tags: html, mysql, toggle

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#music").click(function () {
            $("#musicinfo").toggle("slow");
        });

    });
</script>
```

I use this code to show and hide an `div` but I can only click at the first `div` the second wont work.

This is the `div`:

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $tile)
    {?>
        <div id="music">
            <?php echo $tile['Onderwerp']?>
        </div>
        <div id="musicinfo">
            <?php echo $tile['Omschrijving']?>
        </div>
<?php }?>
```

I am trying to put information out of an mysql into 2 `div`s , 1 for the heading and 1 for information which you can see when you click on the heading `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using same id's in loop, that is wrong and all events only apply for first ID, while others are ignored.

```
foreach ($result as $title) { ?>
    <div class='wrapper'>
       <div class='music'></div>
       <div class='musicInfo'></div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

jQuery function than will looks like this:

```
$('.music').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().find('.musicInfo').toggle();
});
```